# Are random variables $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence

$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=
\left\{\begin{matrix}\frac 27 (x+2y), \mbox{ } 0\leq x \leq1 , 1\leq y \leq 2
\\ 0,  \mbox{   otherwise}\end{matrix}\right.$

My goal is to figure out if $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

$f_{X}(x) = \int_{0}^{2}\frac 27 (x+2y)dy = \frac 27 (x+3) .$

$f_{Y}(y) = \int_{0}^{1}\frac 27 (x+2y)dx = \frac 17 (4y+1)=\frac 27 (2y+\frac12).$

$\frac 27 (x+2y)=f_{X,Y}(x,y) \not= f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)=\frac 27((x+2y)+3+\frac12)=\frac 27((x+2y) +\frac 72)=\frac 27 (x+2y)+1$

Does this mean $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

So are we are expecting to find  $E(XY)\not=E(X)\times E(Y)$ ?

Comment: Note that for $f_X(x)$, $y$ runs from $1$ to $2$, so the integral would be $$\int_1^2 \frac{2}{7}(x+2y)dy$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to go to expectations. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then it is necessary that $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$. If you check that this is not satisfied then $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

Comment: So by , $\frac 27 (x+2y)=f_{X,Y}(x,y) \not= f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y) =\frac 27 (x+2y)+1$ we  conclude $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: You can conclude that $X$ and $Y$ are **not** independent.